# Custom mapping of domain-name to IP within an android app

Tags: android, webview, dns

I have a webapp which is rendered within an android webview. When a user clicks a button the URL http://www.mywebapp.com/ gets rendered.

Is it possible to map this domain to an IP within my local network, for only my android app?

Something like,

`192.168.33.10   mywebapp.com`

Since I'm compiling the android app on my own, I'm hoping that there might be some code-based solution to this question.

**Rejected Approaches:**

1. Rooting the android device to edit its `hosts` file. I'm trying to do this with a shared testing device in my office.
2. Setting up a custom DNS server on the network and having the android phone point to it - this is a global change - whatever solution is used, it should ONLY affect the behavior of the android app and nothing else. Also, I do not have any control/authority over the office wifi.

Answer (score 3):

I think a custom `WebViewClient` would do the trick.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            view.loadUrl(myIp);
        }
        // Else the WebView handles it as normal
        return false; // Indicates the WebView is handling the loading
    }
}
```

From https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using android emulator

Step 1. Download the emulator with X-86 system image **(Important)** Don't select Google Play API's image[image]

Step 2. Once the emulator is set up open terminal and run this command to open the emulator in writable mode.

```
emulator -avd <Your_emulator_name> -partition-size 280 -writable-system
```

Step 3. Once the emulator is opened. Open a new terminal and run this command to download the host file of the emulator to make changes.

```
 adb pull /system/etc/hosts <Your_system_path_to_download_host_file. Example /home/bharath/Desktop/newHost>
```

It will create a new folder called newHost in the desktop and stores the host file in it.

You have to open this file in the text editor and make changes (To add your required ip host entries)

[image: I added a sample host name (dev.something.com) pointing to 192.168.21.1]

Step 4. Now we have to replace this edited host file in the android emulator.

For that we have to run these commands.

4.i. To check whether the emulator is attached or not

```
   adb devices
```

It will return the device/emulator list which is connected.

4.ii. We have to take root permission to write files.

```
   adb root
```

It will return message restarting adbd as root

4.iii. Next we have to remount the system to write files to it

```
   adb remount
```

It will return message as remount succeeded.

4.iv. Next we have to push the edited file into the android emulator

```
   adb push <your edited host file path.Example /home/PFIN/bharath.shet/Desktop/newHost/hosts> /system/etc/hosts
```

It will return file size

Step 5. Inorder to verify the host changes you can download terminal app in the emulator and use ping command to see the change.

```
 ping dev.something.com
```

It will ping to ip 192.168.21.1

Comment: I think this is best solution. You don't need any other network settings etc.